# Mocking a method inside another method called without using class object

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a method, called from another method without using the class object. In the specified code, I want to mock methodA(), which is calling methodB(), without using the object.

I cannot change anything in the existing class.

```
class A{

public String methodA(){
//do something
String s = methodB(employee);
}

public String methodB(Employee e){
 e.getId();
}
}
```

I have already tried to do :

1. Mockito.doReturn("id").when(objectOfA).methodB(employee);
2. when(methodB(employee)).thenReturn("id");

Comment: Class A is under test ? and you want to mock `methodA()`. Is that correct @Abhi

Comment: yes Class A is under test. I want to test methodA() by mocking methodB()

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = mock(A.class);
when(a.methodA()).thenReturn("Whatever you want");
```